# How to format on SO from a Dual boot computer with Grub

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub, zorin

My computer is dual boot, running W10 as default and Zorin 15. I want to replace Zorin to Ubuntu, but I want to make sure that my W10 will not die during this transition, I have a lot of stuff on it.

How about grub? Will I have to reinstall it?

This is my first time with dual boot, thanks.

Comment: EFI or BIOS boot style?

Comment: I guess it's UEFI, I have a ASUS MB

Comment: Your is a not-issue specific question; it's hard for us to properly help you; please, read this guide [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows] and feel free to update your question if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prerquisites

- Have means to start Windows even if installing Ubuntu fails. For BIOS boot style, I recommend preparing a Super Grub2 Disk. With EFI boot style, it is sufficient to check whether Windows can be selected by the EFI.
- Have a copy of everything important. Think about all the data in Zorin.
- Know which partition Zorin is installed on (I assume a single partition installation style).
- Have a Ubuntu setup medium.

## Setup

When the setup asks where to install to, select the custom option. It should show you a list of all partitions on your disk. Double check that there is not a single checkmark in the "format" column.
Now find the Zorin partition. Select

- format: yes (this will remove Zorin and the grub configuration)
- file-system: ext4 (the default)
- use as: / (root entry)

. Also chose to install grub on the disk (the old grub installation will be unable to find its configuration data as this is often stored on the partition with Linux).

As long as you do not tell the installer to touch your Windows partition, all the data on that partition will be preserved.

Comment: Thank's @Hermann, I appreciate that